# Android activity dynamic layout updates

Tags: android-activity, android, android-view

I am trying to create a small Android App. The app will have four modes. The top part of the display will contain four buttons to switch between these modes, and this part of the display will not change.  The rest of the display will change depending which button has been clicked on. It will contain a table with `TextViews` or images.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to create the table layout programmatically?
- How should I approach switching between modes:-

  1. Four separate `Activity` classes?
  2. One `Activity` and programmatically change the bottom part of it?
  3. Should I create one base `Activity` with buttons and extend it?

What would be the best option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create layout by code is not the good solution. If your table layout is simple, I think it's not a big problem.

Here is a simple code how to create a layout by code :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                layout.addView(new TextView(this));
            setContentView(layout);
    }
```

And as you see, it looks ugly !

Hope this help :)

**@: Edit for additional question about Relative Layout:**

In `RelativeLayout` (and some Layout of android), there is an object `LayoutParams`to determine some properties of sub-layout (TextView, Button... is called sub-layout too if you put in other Layout)

Here is an example :

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView.getId());

layout.addView(textView, params);
```

You should notice `BELOW`, it is one of many int constant such as `Right_of`.... You can see on Android Document about these.

Comment: I am using Relative Layout. How do I set "below" location of the layout programtically? Thank you.

Comment: @SeanKilb I have edited my post. feel free to reply which point you don't know

Comment: I will create Relative Layout by XML. I will add a LinearLayout with all the buttons to the RelativeLayout by XML. Quesition - how do I add TableLayout to the right site of buttons programatically? I have tried to use RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1); But the app keeps crashing. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for help hqt. I was able to create an app which dynamically updates the layout of the bottom part of the screen with a button click. But there is an issue. I decided to go with the TableLayout. It works when I click first time, it creates additional TableRows with TextViews. When I click second time on the same button or another button the app crashes. I have to remove the old TableRows dynamically before I create a new ones. How do I do that?  Is there like a general removeAll() method? Thank you again for your help.